# How to identify Google play apps compatibile with Genymotion?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, genymotion, apktool

When I head on Google Play from a virtualized device, several common apps are not available, since they are incompatible with the v-device.

I would like to understand which is the missing  device feature. Therefore I downloaded the APK using the cloud service https://apps.evozi.com/ and a compatible device. Then I extracted and decrypted `AndroidManifest.xml` by means of the [Apktool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool), using:

```
apktool d myapp.apk
```

Inside I looked for `uses-feature`:

```
grep '<uses-feature' AndroidManifest.xml
```

which gives:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

However, OpenGL ES seems supported since [Genymotion v2.16](https://www.genymotion.com/product-release-note/desktop/).

Where else should I look?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why Apps are not available on Play Store from Genymotion:

1. Without ARM translation tools, only apps for x86/x86_64 will be available on the store, the others will be hidden
2. With ARM translation tools, only apps for armv7 will be available (arm64 is not supported by Genymotion)
3. Genymotion virtual devices are **rooted**, therefore apps which detect root will also be unavailable from the store
4. Genymotion uses a custom AOSP rom, apps which detect AOSP roms will be marked as not compatible with the device in the store

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an alternative to which works better?

Comment: You can try Google Android emulator, but you may encounter similare issues. Some app developpers just don't want their apps to run on anything else than an unrooted real device.